# what is the bpy.props.Property of these specific sliders?

Tags: python, properties

trying to implement these using `bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.`slider property name here`Property()` and what would i put below it? for example i know i would need to do `default=0.0,` under it but what about minimum and maximum values?

[.py file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dNl6Lr25WppfEi-dEtAlOZtiUP1nAtRo?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Hello, your question is a bit hard to understand, could you rephrase it ? Do you want to know how you could implement a slider in the UI that's filling up depending on its min and max values ?

Comment: hi, im sorry for the bad phrasing im very new to python. but yes thats exactly what i am wanting to happen

Comment: Here's all the possible arguments : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty you can simply use `min = 0,` `max = 10,` for instance